# Weird behavior when wrapping purrr::map within dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr, tibble

I am running into some errors I do not fully understand when trying to call `purrr::map` around `dplyr::mutate`. The reproducible code is as follows:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)
# data 
test_dset <- structure(list(genus = c("Aureitalea", "Aureivirga", "Auricoccucs"), 
                            t_count = c(0L, 0L, 0L), n = c(1L, 1L, 1L), 
                            ncbi_id = list("1176327", "1433990", character(0)), 
                            g_test = list(c(`1176327` = 0), 
                                          c(`1433990` = 0), 
                                          structure(numeric(0), .Names = character(0)))), 
                       class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                       row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                       groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L), 
                                                                 ptype = integer(0), 
                                                                 class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
                                          row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                                          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
test_dset
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   genus       t_count     n ncbi_id   g_test   
#>   <chr>         <int> <int> <list>    <list>   
#> 1 Aureitalea        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]>
#> 2 Aureivirga        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]>
#> 3 Auricoccucs       0     1 <chr [0]> <dbl [0]>
# process a vector of pvals 
proc_gtest <- function(pvals){
  if (length(pvals) == 0){
    return(NA_character_)
  } 
  sig <- which(pvals < 0.05)
  if (length(sig) == 0){
    return(NA_character_)
  } else {
    return(names(pvals)[sig])
  }
}

# returns errors 
test_dset |> mutate(ncbi_filt = map(g_test, proc_gtest))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `ncbi_filt`.
#> ℹ `ncbi_filt = map(g_test, proc_gtest)`.
#> ℹ `ncbi_filt` must be size 1, not 0.
#> ℹ Did you mean: `ncbi_filt = list(map(g_test, proc_gtest))` ?
#> ℹ The error occurred in row 3.
# this is okay 
map(test_dset$g_test, proc_gtest)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "1176327"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "1433990"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] NA
# adding list doesn't work because it returns a list of NULL 
# with names as the quantities I wanted. 
test_dset |> mutate(ncbi_filt = list(map(g_test, proc_gtest))) |> pull(ncbi_filt)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$`1176327`
#> NULL
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$`1433990`
#> NULL
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> named list()
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
#>  os       macOS Mojave 10.14.6        
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/New_York            
#>  date     2021-10-13                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  ! package     * version date       lib source        
#>    assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    backports     1.2.1   2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    cli           3.0.1   2021-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    crayon        1.4.1   2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    DBI           1.1.1   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    dplyr       * 1.0.7   2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    fansi         0.5.0   2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    generics      0.1.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    knitr         1.34    2021-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    lifecycle     1.0.0   2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    pillar        1.6.2   2021-07-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    purrr       * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  P R.cache       0.15.0  2021-04-30 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  P R.methodsS3   1.8.1   2020-08-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  P R.oo          1.24.0  2020-08-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  P R.utils       2.11.0  2021-09-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    rlang         0.4.11  2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    rmarkdown     2.11    2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [3] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    stringi       1.7.4   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  P styler        1.6.2   2021-09-23 [?] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    tibble      * 3.1.4   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    tidyselect    1.1.1   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    vctrs         0.3.8   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    withr         2.4.2   2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    xfun          0.26    2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>    yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#> 
#> [1] /Users/quangnguyen/research/microbe_set_trait/renv/library/R-4.1/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
#> [2] /private/var/folders/fs/hp4_8vfs665_nqytkhjc8s6w0000gn/T/Rtmp6ZA9pW/renv-system-library
#> [3] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library
#> 
#>  P ── Loaded and on-disk path mismatch.
```

My understanding is that the error is due to the fact that the function being mapped returns nothing at row 3. The solution `dplyr` gave is that I should wrap everything in a `list`.

However:

- I am using the original `map` which should already return a list (other tutorials on using `map` to transform list columns for tibbles also did not wrap everything around `list`). Wrapping this inside a `list` returns a `list` of `NULL` elements where the things that I want to extract are set as names of this new list.
- My function does return values even if the element in the list is empty (returns `NA_character_`.

As seen in the reprex, the normal `map` function works and returns a list of length 3 with the empty row having an NA assigned to it as per the logic of the custom function. Right now I'm working around this by just generating a separate list and attach it to the data frame later, however I would love to understand what I'm looking at!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with `rowwise` group attribute.  As we are looping over each element in `map`, just `ungroup`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
test_dset %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(ncbi_filt = map(g_test, proc_gtest))
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  genus       t_count     n ncbi_id   g_test    ncbi_filt
  <chr>         <int> <int> <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 Aureitalea        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <chr [1]>
2 Aureivirga        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <chr [1]>
3 Auricoccucs       0     1 <chr [0]> <dbl [0]> <chr [1]>
```

Or use `map_chr` to return as a vector (as there is one single value returned)

```
test_dset %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(ncbi_filt = map_chr(g_test, proc_gtest))
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  genus       t_count     n ncbi_id   g_test    ncbi_filt
  <chr>         <int> <int> <list>    <list>    <chr>    
1 Aureitalea        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> 1176327  
2 Aureivirga        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> 1433990  
3 Auricoccucs       0     1 <chr [0]> <dbl [0]> <NA>
```

---

If there is a `rowwise` attribute, we can directly apply the function and get the output in a `list` (if the output returns length > 1 or of different structure)

```
test_dset %>%
    mutate(ncbi_filt = list(proc_gtest(g_test)))
# A tibble: 3 × 6
# Rowwise: 
  genus       t_count     n ncbi_id   g_test    ncbi_filt
  <chr>         <int> <int> <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 Aureitalea        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <chr [1]>
2 Aureivirga        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> <chr [1]>
3 Auricoccucs       0     1 <chr [0]> <dbl [0]> <chr [1]>
```

The function returns a single value, so we don't need to wrap with `list` as well

```
test_dset %>% 
    mutate(ncbi_filt = proc_gtest(g_test))
# A tibble: 3 × 6
# Rowwise: 
  genus       t_count     n ncbi_id   g_test    ncbi_filt
  <chr>         <int> <int> <list>    <list>    <chr>    
1 Aureitalea        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> 1176327  
2 Aureivirga        0     1 <chr [1]> <dbl [1]> 1433990  
3 Auricoccucs       0     1 <chr [0]> <dbl [0]> <NA>
```